# Google Cloud SQL - PostgreSQL has some way to add extensions by gcloud

Tags: sql, cloud, google-cloud-sql

At start it gives me access to login, but I do not know if I can in that way add extensions like postgis.

-> gcloud beta sql connect backend-test1 --user=postgres

Answer (score 2):

Connect to the database and run:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no separate `gcloud` command to add extension.

To install an extension, you use the [CREATE EXTENSION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createextension.html) command with the psql tool. For information about using a specific extension, see the documentation for that extension.

Comment: By doing so it tells me that it does not support, have you tried it in Google Cloud?